# Возможно ли получить CSS свойства элемента?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Возможно ли как то получить определённое свойство элемента из CSS файла ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно обратиться к DOM из JS

```
document.getElementById('ololo')[0].style[background]
```

Comment: Здорово, cпасибо большое!